# Como fazer upload de um vídeo usando multipart e Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Tenho uma aplicação que está sendo escrita usando Node.Js, nela uso o FFmpeg para criar um vídeo a partir de uma webcam. Preciso fazer o upload dele no servidor usando uma requisição POST. Então a pergunta é:

**Como fazer upload de um vídeo usando multipart e Node.js?**

*Ps1.: O vídeo é um arquivo local cujo caminho vai ser passado por parâmetro! Criar um formulário para escolher o arquivo não é a resposta.*

*Ps2.: Não estou usando o Express.*

*Ps3.: O servidor roda na internet, para essa requisição recebe os dados em um endereço como: aplicativo.com.br/v1/videos. Não tenho acesso em que pasta serão salvos nem a porta de comunicação. E ele ainda precisa enviar parâmetros no header e no corpo da requisição.*

---

**Edit 1:** Consegui fazer a requisição usando o módulo *request*. O problema é que preciso acrescentar um parâmetro inteiro no corpo da requisição. `"testeId": 7451109`. Como proceder? Segue código até o momento.

**Edit 2:** Atualizando o código.

Código:

```
request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://" + options.host + options.path,
        formData: {
            upload_type: "mp4",
            file: fs.createReadStream(options.nomeVideo)
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'access-token': chaveCriptografada
        }
    },

    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(body);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, da uma olhada nessa lib.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Exemplo completo:

https://github.com/wandersonpereira/multer-sem-express

Este é um exemplo sem utilizar o express. Para utiliza-lo basta somente ter uma requisição que trafegue um arquivo.

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

var multer  = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})
  
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');  

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return
        }
        // Everything went fine
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    });    
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Como eu disse na pergunta, eu não estou usando Express. Mas valeu pela resposta!

Comment: Não precisa usar o express, coloquei acima um exemplo de código utilizado o http padrão do node.

Comment: No caso do meu servidor, ele já está rodando na internet, um site como aplicativo.com.br/v1/videos. Eu não tenho a porta de comunicação. Ainda tem jeito de usar o multer? Se sim, como proceder?